# can't calculate numeric field with ogr python

Tags: python, osgeo, gdal-python-binding

I have created two functions: one to add a field to a layer and one to calculate a field. I am having issues with the calculate field function when trying to calculate values for a numeric column. I do not get an error, but the column is blank after the code runs (it was blank to begin with). I've tried both OFTInteger and OFTReal as field types with the same result. Here are the functions:

```
def add_field(lyr, field_name, field_type):
    field = ogr.FieldDefn(field_name, field_type)
    field.SetWidth(50)
    lyr.CreateField(field)

def calc_field(calc_lyr, field, exp):
    for feature in calc_lyr:
        geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
        area = geom.GetArea()
        feature.SetField(field, exp)
        calc_lyr.SetFeature(feature)
```

and here are the function calls to add and calculate a numeric field:

```
add_field(dxf_lyr, 'color', ogr.OFTInteger)
calc_field(dxf_lyr, 'color', 150)
```

The field gets added, but the values don't get caculated. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you close the dataset at the end using something like `ds.Destroy()`? It might also be necessary to repack it using `ds.ExecuteSQL("REPACK " + lyr.GetName())`

Comment: thanks for your note. I don't close it, but can try that. But when I run the same dataset through both functions to add and calculate a string field, it works..but maybe I need to close it each time, the string field was the first one I added and calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always used the layer.GetNextFeature() method with consistent success. 
i.e your function would look like this:

```
def calc_field(calc_lyr, field, exp):
    calc_lyr.ResetReading()    #reset the pointer
    feature= calc_lyr.GetNextFeature()    #prime the pump
    while feature:
        geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
        area = geom.GetArea()
        feature.SetField(field, exp)
        calc_lyr.SetFeature(feature)
        feature= calc_lyr.GetNextFeature() #get the next feature, or None if at the end of the layer
```

Comment: Something else I am wondering and thought I would ask before starting a new post, how do you reference existing fields when calculating values for a new field? say I want to concatenate two fields as the value in the new field, i'm not sure how to do this here

Comment: Start a new post so the question gets more visability

Comment: It is important to note (as explained in my answer) that the reason it failed was because you cannot iterate features with the chosen syntax: `for feature in calc_lyr`. It effectively did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be your use of iteration of the layer. The `Layer` class in the OGR Python API *has* an `__iter__` method, but it will not work for you in this case. There are other ways of iterating features such as `Layer.next` and `Layer.GetNextFeature`, but these are challenging to use.

The simplest way to iterate features (in my experience) is to use one of the indexing methods, which are `Layer.__getitem__` or `Layer.GetFeature`. These are usually used in conjunction with the `Layer.GetFeatureCount` method:

- `__getitem__` syntax:

  ```
  for i in range(calc_lyr.GetFeatureCount()):
      feature = calc_lyr[i]  # Note, only single integer slices are supported
      area = feature.GetGeometryRef().GetArea()
  ```
- Using the `Layer.GetFeature` method:

  ```
  for i in range(calc_lyr.GetFeatureCount()):
      feature = calc_lyr.GetFeature(i)
      area = feature.GetGeometryRef().GetArea()
  ```